# How fixed position of element after applying animation

Tags: android, animation

Have problem: don't know how to apply new position to element after animation (applyd to this element)
For example have .xml animation

```
<translate
    android:duration="6000"
    android:fromXDelta="1000"
    android:toXDelta="720" 
    />
```

of translation and after applyin it for my button
`button.setAnimation(translate)`, 
button back to previous position.
How apply new position to button(actually the position when animation finish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with fillEnabled=true & fillAfter=true, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:zAdjustment="top">
    <translate
    android:duration="6000"
    android:fromXDelta="1000"
    android:toXDelta="720" 
    />
</set>
```